# What to do with answers inspired by BioStars?

Tags: discussion

Out of curiosity I followed the first of Pierre's BioStars links from the comments on the FASTA lengths question, and noticed that our [currently accepted answer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/48/215) bears a strong resemblance to [this answer on BioStars](https://www.biostars.org/p/72433/#72434).

I'm not trying to start anything, or accuse anyone here, but presumably we're not here to mirror answers already available elsewhere. So I'm just wondering whether there is a policy on this sort of thing, and whether anyone knows what the license for BioStars answers is?

Comment: Just to note, let's not make it OK to post "link only" answers.

Comment: Did this change? The currently accepted answer is yours, and the Biostars answer you link is a one-sentence reference to FastQC (and no reference to FastQC is made anywhere in answers here).

Comment: It seems the answer I was referring to has been deleted

Comment: @SamStudio8 Ah, that’s a shame, because now there’s no single reference to FastQC. At any rate the BioStars answer was a single sentence so even if it were copied verbatim it would be unlikely to be (a) copyrightable or (b) ethically ownable.

Comment: The question here was specifically about nanopore reads. FastQC is not appropriate for long reads, and likely to be harmful due to the false error flags that it will throw up.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Regarding licensing for biostars posts, they're Creative Commons (version 4 if that matters). I'm personally of the opinion that biostars posts should at least be linked to so people can see where the information comes from and the original author there can get recognised. Others are, of course, free to disagree with that, but regardless I fully support your stance that there should be some sort of rough policy.

Comment: I would hesitate to use biostar as a source of information. There are low quality and sometimes completely wrong accepted answers. I would prefer to link the manual of a tool or a paper instead of biostar.

Comment: I don't think anyone is suggesting blindly believing things written on biostars (or anywhere else for that matter). When one uses any source it's one's own onus to ensure its reliability.

Comment: Sure, that sounds more than reasonable...